# Google Cloud Platform Logging - reduce noise by excluding liveness_check and readiness_check

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

My GCP Logging logs are too noisy. They are cluttered by liveness_check and readiness_check entries. What query do I need to log everything except liveness_check and readiness_check? Screenshot follows thanks

[image]

Comment: You can set multiple [exclusion filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions), letting you exclude matching log entries from being routed to the sink's destination or from being ingested by Cloud Logging. You create exclusion filters by using the [Logging query language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language). Do check out the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvkiaFV_unc) on Exclusion filter .Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

resource.type="gae_app" AND
(httpRequest.requestUrl="/readiness_check" OR httpRequest.requestUrl="/liveness_check")

Can you check the query first? above code will work in Log explorer or not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the answer by @Genshiro I saved the following as my "no noise" filter

```
httpRequest.requestUrl!="/readiness_check" AND
httpRequest.requestUrl!="/liveness_check" AND
httpRequest.requestUrl!="/nginx_metrics" AND
NOT textPayload:"Health checks:" AND
NOT jsonPayload.message:"This is a normal event of healthy VMs" AND
NOT jsonPayload.message:"Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval." AND
NOT jsonPayload.message:"buffer flush took longer time than" AND
NOT jsonPayload.message:"detected rotation of" AND
NOT jsonPayload.message:"following tail of"
```

Note that the docs for constructing such a filter are [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries)